# Differentiating $h(x) = x f(x) + g(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If i have a definition like this:

$h(x) := x f(x) + g(x)$

What would $h'(x)$ be? Without the $x$ preceeding $f(x)$, it would just be 
$h'(x) := f'(x) + g'(x)$, right?

How does it work with the preceeding $x$, which i believe spells "$x$ times $f(x)$"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct about the derivative of $f(x)+g(x)$. To take care of the "preceeding $x$," we simply use the product rule.

If $h(x) := x f(x) + g(x)$

then $h'(x) = (x f(x))' + (g(x))'$

Using the product rule, we find that $(xf(x))'=f(x)+xf'(x)$.

Thus, $h'(x) = f(x)+xf'(x) + g'(x)$.

Comment: Ah yes of course. I can't believe im in university and still forget stuff like this. The product rule goes like this: $(f(x)*g(x))' = f'(x)*g(x)+f(x)*g'(x)$, right? And because $x' = 1$, only $f(x)$ is left on the left (lol).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

The sum rule says

$$(u(x)+v(x))'\\
=\lim \limits_{h\to0}\frac{u(x+h)+v(x+h)-u(x)-v(x)}h\\
=\lim \limits_{h\to0}\frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}h+\frac{v(x+h)-v(x)}h\\
=u'(x)+v'(x).$$

The product rule isn't much more complicated,

$$(u(x)v(x))'\\
=\lim \limits_{h\to0}\frac{u(x+h)v(x+h)-u(x)v(x)}h\\
=\lim \limits_{h\to0}\frac{(u(x+h)-u(x))v(x+h)+u(x)(v(x+h)-v(x))}h\\
=\lim \limits_{h\to0}\frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}hv(x+h)+u(x)\lim \limits_{h\to0}\frac{v(x+h)-v(x)}h\\
=u'(x)v(x)+u(x)v'(x),$$
as $v(x+h)\to v(x)$.

Equipped with these two rules, you can solve the problem.

Comment: I went ahead and added the limits. I believe that they make the reasons for the manipulations clearer, as derivatives are based off of limits. If you feel they don't help, feel free to rollback.

Comment: Ah yes. I have a general question though: Most of the time for  a $\lim \limits_{h\to0}$ we can just presume $h = 0$, right? But what if an equation has no real value for $h = 0$? Is there a rule on what to do then?

Comment: That's the fundamental point of limits. They allow us to examine functions as we **approach** some value. We never actually assume $h=0$, just examine what happens as $h$ approaches it.

Comment: "Most of the time we can just presume $h=0$": when computing derivatives this never occurs, as the denominator may not be $0$. You will soon learn about *indeterminate forms*.

Comment: Alright - it seems i completely misunderstood this then. I just looked at the formula and thought "but how can i get rid of the h?". Thanks for all your answers, but now i cant decide which one to accept...